# APACHE несколько значений в loadmodule. ModPageSpeed

Tags: apache

Использую Google Mod Pagee Speed.

Запретил изменения png, jpg, jpeg так:

```
ModPagespeedDisallow "*.png" 
ModPagespeedDisallow "*.jpg" 
ModPagespeedDisallow "*.jpeg"
```

Не подскажите как объеденить паттерны в одну строку? Пытался на подобии `"*(.png|.jpg|.jpeg)"` - не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Директива `ModPagespeedDisallow` не поддерживает regex-like штуки.

А только wildcard:

> Note: Wildcards include * which matches any 0 or more characters, and
>   ?, which matches exactly one character. Unlike Unix shells, the /
>   directory separator is not special, and can be matched by either * or
>   ?. The resources are always expanded into their absolute form before
>   expanding.